# Variant The knapsack in java with PD

Tags: java

I have the problem solved Knapsack in PD , but I want to make a variant. I want to minimize instead than maximizing. We must change the "getObjetivo" and "getObjetivoEsperado" methods, but I do not know .
Attach my code.

```
public class ProblemaMochilaPD implements ProblemaPD<Multiset<ObjetoMochila>, Integer> {

    private static ProblemaMochilaPD problemaInicial;
    private static Integer capacidadInicial;
    private int index;
    private Double valorSolucion = Double.MIN_VALUE;

    public static List<Integer> multiplicidadesMaximas;
    public static List<ObjetoMochila> objetos;
    public static Integer numeroDeObjetos;


    public static ProblemaMochilaPD create(String fichero, Integer c) { 
        ProblemaMochila.leeObjetosDisponibles(fichero);
        ProblemaMochilaPD.objetos = ProblemaMochila.getObjetosDisponibles();
        ProblemaMochilaPD.numeroDeObjetos = ProblemaMochilaPD.objetos.size();
        ProblemaMochilaPD.multiplicidadesMaximas = ProblemaMochila.getObjetosDisponibles()
                .stream().mapToInt(x->x.getNumMaxDeUnidades())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());          
        ProblemaMochilaPD.capacidadInicial = c;
        ProblemaMochilaPD.problemaInicial = new ProblemaMochilaPD(0, 0, 0.);
        return ProblemaMochilaPD.problemaInicial;
    }

    public static ProblemaMochilaPD create(int index,int pesoAcumulado,double valorAcumulado) {
        ProblemaMochilaPD p = new ProblemaMochilaPD(index, pesoAcumulado,valorAcumulado);
        return p;
    }

    private Integer pesoAcumulado;
    private Integer capacidadRestante;
    private Double valorAcumulado;


    private ProblemaMochilaPD(int index, int pesoAcumulado, double valorAcumulado) {
        this.index = index;
        this.pesoAcumulado = pesoAcumulado;
        this.capacidadRestante = capacidadInicial-this.pesoAcumulado;
        this.valorAcumulado = valorAcumulado;
    }   

    private Boolean constraints(Integer a) {
        return this.pesoAcumulado+a*objetos.get(index).getPeso() <= capacidadInicial;
    }   

    @Override
    public Tipo getTipo(){
        return Tipo.Min;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return ProblemaMochilaPD.numeroDeObjetos-index+1;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> getAlternativas() {
        List<Integer> ls = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, ProblemaMochilaPD.multiplicidadesMaximas.get(this.index))
                .filter(x->this.constraints(x))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.reverse(ls);
        return ls;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean esCasoBase() {
        return this.capacidadRestante == 0 ||  index == ProblemaMochilaPD.numeroDeObjetos-1;
    }

    @Override
    public Sp<Integer> getSolucionCasoBase() {
        Integer peso = objetos.get(index).getPeso();
        int num = Math.min(capacidadRestante/peso,objetos.get(index).getNumMaxDeUnidades()) ;
        Double val = (double) num*objetos.get(index).getValor();
        valorSolucion = val;
        return Sp.create(num, val);
    }

    @Override
    public ProblemaPD<Multiset<ObjetoMochila>, Integer> getSubProblema(Integer a, int np) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(np==0);
        Integer pesoAcumulado = this.pesoAcumulado+a*objetos.get(index).getPeso();
        Double valorAcumulado = this.valorAcumulado+a*objetos.get(index).getValor();
        return ProblemaMochilaPD.create(index+1,pesoAcumulado,valorAcumulado);
    }

    @Override
    public Sp<Integer> combinaSolucionesParciales(Integer a, List<Sp<Integer>> ls) {
        Sp<Integer> r = ls.get(0);
        Double valor = a*objetos.get(index).getValor()+r.propiedad;
        return Sp.create(a, valor);
    }

    @Override
    public Sp<Integer> seleccionaAlternativa(List<Sp<Integer>> ls) {
        Sp<Integer> r =ls.stream().filter(x -> x.propiedad != null).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(null);
        valorSolucion = r!=null ? r.propiedad : Double.MIN_VALUE;
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumeroSubProblemas(Integer a) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Multiset<ObjetoMochila> getSolucionReconstruida(Sp<Integer> sp) {
        Multiset<ObjetoMochila> m = HashMultiset.create();
        m.add(ProblemaMochilaPD.objetos.get(this.index), sp.alternativa);
        return m;
    }

    @Override
    public Multiset<ObjetoMochila> getSolucionReconstruida(Sp<Integer> sp, List<Multiset<ObjetoMochila>> ls) {
        Multiset<ObjetoMochila> m = ls.get(0);
        m.add(ProblemaMochilaPD.objetos.get(this.index), sp.alternativa);
        return m;
    }


    @Override
    public Double getObjetivoEstimado(Integer a) {  
        return this.valorAcumulado+this.getCotaSuperiorValorEstimado(a);
    }

    @Override
    public Double getObjetivo() {
        return this.valorAcumulado+this.valorSolucion;
    }


    /**
     * @pre a está contenida en getAlternativas()
     * @param a Una alternativa de this
     * @return Una cota superior del valor de la solución del problema this si se escoge la alternativa a
     */
    public Integer getCotaSuperiorValorEstimado(Integer a){
        Double r = 0.;
        Double capacidadRestante = (double) (capacidadInicial-pesoAcumulado);
        Double nu =(double) a;
        int ind = this.index;
        while(true) {
            r = r+nu*objetos.get(ind).getValor();
            capacidadRestante = capacidadRestante-nu*objetos.get(ind).getPeso();
            ind++;
            if(ind >= objetos.size() || capacidadRestante <= 0.) break;
            nu = Math.min(multiplicidadesMaximas.get(ind),capacidadRestante/objetos.get(ind).getPeso());            
        } 
        return (int)Math.ceil(r);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((capacidadRestante == null) ? 0 : capacidadRestante
                        .hashCode());
        result = prime * result + index;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ProblemaMochilaPD))
            return false;
        ProblemaMochilaPD other = (ProblemaMochilaPD) obj;
        if (capacidadRestante == null) {
            if (other.capacidadRestante != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!capacidadRestante.equals(other.capacidadRestante))
            return false;
        if (index != other.index)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + index + ", "
                + capacidadRestante + ")";
    }
}
```

I add the ObjetoMochila class to view its properties .

```
public class ObjetoMochila implements Comparable<ObjetoMochila>{

    public static ObjetoMochila create(Integer valor,Integer peso, Integer countMax) {
        return new ObjetoMochila(valor, peso, countMax);
    }

    public static ObjetoMochila create(String s) {
        return new ObjetoMochila(s);
    }

    private static Integer nCodigo = 0;

    private Integer codigo;
    private Integer valor;
    private Integer peso;
    private Integer numMaxDeUnidades;

    ObjetoMochila(Integer valor, Integer peso, Integer countMax){
        this.codigo = nCodigo;
        nCodigo++;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.numMaxDeUnidades = countMax;
    }   
    ObjetoMochila(String s){        
        String[] v = s.split("[ ,]");
        Integer ne = v.length;
        if(ne != 3) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Formato no adecuado en línea  "+s); 
        valor = new Integer(v[0]);
        peso = new Integer(v[1]);
        numMaxDeUnidades = new Integer(v[2]);
        this.codigo = nCodigo;
        nCodigo++;
    }   
    public Integer getPeso() {
        return peso;
    }
    public Integer getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public Integer getNumMaxDeUnidades() {
        return numMaxDeUnidades;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ObjetoMochila o) {
        int r = getRatioValorPeso().compareTo(o.getRatioValorPeso());
        if(r == 0){
            r = getCodigo().compareTo(o.getCodigo());
        }
        return r;
    }   
    public Double getRatioValorPeso() {
        return ((double)valor)/peso;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<"+codigo+","+valor+","+peso+","+numMaxDeUnidades+">";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ObjetoMochila))
            return false;
        ObjetoMochila other = (ObjetoMochila) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is PD? Is it [Programación Dinámica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_din%C3%A1mica) also known as [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) which is abbreviated with DP? You might want to tryout [spanish.SO.com](http://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Is DP (Dynamic programming)